# Laravel mail sending but not getting at inbox

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to send email with laravel and smtp here bellow is my code

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST='mail.domain.net'
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='supports@domain.net'
MAIL_PASSWORD='mail account password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="admin@domain.net"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Mailable extends

```
class ForgotPasswordMail extends Mailable
{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $ForgotPassword;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->details = $details;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject($this->details['subject'])
        ->view('email.forgotpassword')
        ->from($this->details['from'], $this->details['from'])
         ->with(
            [
                'testVarOne' => '1',
                'testVarTwo' => '2',
            ])
        ;
  }
}
```

send mail controller

```
$details = [
            'to' => $email,
            'from' => 'from@example.com',
            'subject' => $subject,
            'title' => 'example title',
            "body"  => $body
        ];

        if(Mail::to($to_email)->send(new ForgotPasswordMail($details))){
            return true;
        }
```

I am not getting any error when I fire the controller but I not getting any email at my inbox. please help me for tihs

Comment: Did you check it with mailtrap?

Comment: no I am checking with my cpanel smtp email accounts settings

Comment: I have tried with mailtrap, now I am getting message at mailtrap dashboard, but not going email to the user email

Comment: Then this is your smtp server issue. Try changing the mail port

Comment: but why email not going to user inbox? only receiving at mailtrap dashboard

Comment: Mailtrap is used just for testing, it will just catch that email and show it to you, so you don't even have to use real email addresses when using Mailtrap. If the email is not being sent using your domain's SMTP settings, then either the settings are wrong (PORT, etc.) or they have a problem with their servers.

Answer (score 0):

its queueable mail so need to run listener

> php artisan queue:listen